# How to put a treeview in a scrollpane and only have the scrollbar which belongs to the scrollpane

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-8, fxml

```
    <ScrollPane>
    <content>
        <TreeView fx:id="tree"/>
       </content>
    </ScrollPane>
```

or

```
    <VBox>
   <children>
   <ScrollPane VBox.vgrow="always">
    <content>
        <TreeView fx:id="tree"/>
       </content>
   </ScrollPane>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

I want to put a treeview component in a scrollpane component. When i put a lot of items in the treeview, the scrollbar of the treeview appears and the the scrollbar of the scrollpane doesn't have its height which changes (The scrollbar of the scrollpane is shown thanks to the ScrollbarPolicy). Is there a way to bind the scrollbar of the scrollpane to the treeview component ?

Comment: Yout want the scrollbar of the ScrollPane to become visible and usable instead of the one of the TreeView when items are added to the TreeView?

Comment: May I ask why you want this? Note the `TreeView` doesn't necessarily grow in height when there is more data than room to display it; without the increase in height, the `ScrollPane` can't know it needs to show the scroll bar. But what is the problem with using the built-in scrolling functionality of `TreeView`?

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I need to have a scrollpane. In fact, i use the drag and drop in order to move a treeview component from one place to another (in the treeview too). I have put a functionnality which permits to automatically go down the scrollpane when the component is put outside the scrollpane during a drag operation (the component is not dropped yet). This operation only works with a scrollpane. I tried to use the scrollbar of the treeview but it doesn't work.The operation is realised thanks to a timeline which changes the scrollbar value.